# ERROR in main.js from Terser when compiling with webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, terser

So I'm trying to run webpack to compile my code, but when I run `npx webpack --config webpack.config.js` I get the following error:

```
ERROR in main.js from Terser
Invalid assignment [main.js:78674,15]
```

There's not much to go off of, I'm not even sure where to look. Does anyone have any ideas what might be causing this?

Here's my webpack config:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './server.js',
    target: "node",
    output: {
        filename: 'main.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        publicPath: "/public/"
    },
    module:{
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.m?js$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
                        plugins: ['@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import']
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            'express-handlebars': 'handlebars/dist/handlebars.js'
        }
    }
};
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

RESOLVED:

This was an error with assignment where I was assigning process.end.NODE_ENV to a string, which was being compiled into two string assignment:

```
"node-env" = "dev-env"
```

I resolved this but not minimizing my webpack build:

```
    optimization: {
        minimize: false
    }
```

Then finding the assignment error line from the error output, in the non minified bundle.

```
Invalid function parameter [bundle.js:186393,23]
```

Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: Probably it's late now but have you solved your minify problem?